# Integration substituting $u=\sin x$ or $u=\cos x$

Tags: integration

> Our tutor have written the following:
>
> let there be $\int R(\cos x,\sin x)dx$
>   
>   1. If $R$ a rational function such that $R(-\cos x, \sin x)=-R(\cos x,\sin x)$, use the substitution $u=\sin x$.
>   
>   2.If $R$ a rational function such that $R(\cos x,-\sin x)=-R(\cos x,\sin x)$, use the substitution $u=\cos x$.

All that it is saying the if we have a function with $\cos$ and $\sin$ we should choose the substitution based on the one that is in the odd power?

Comment: The phrasing "the one that is in the odd power" alludes to very restricted cases. The interest of these rules (often called "règles de Bioche" in French) is that they allow to treat many more rational fractions.

Comment: @Did, it is indeed restrictive, but is OP's thought not correct?  $R$ is a rational function which means $R$ itself is pretty restricted.

Comment: As @Did commented, have  a look at https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gles_de_Bioche ; This is in French but it will not make any problem to you.

Comment: So to see if a function agree with the rule, I should add the minus sign to sin or cos and see if I can move it out?